# Identical directories on Linux file system are not symlinks. What else they could be?

Tags: linux, filesystems, symbolic-link, symlink

I found two directories on some of my systems which are completely the same. All subdirectories and all files are the same. When I delete a file in one directory it disappears in other too. This would indicate sym links, doesn't it?
But ls -s doesn't show any links on either side.
What could it be?
Thanks.

Comment: What are the directories?

Comment: What does `mount` say?

Comment: @Reb, You mean two directories in separate locations? Can you see, if you can run this command: `incrontab -l`

Comment: @dr01: Directories are /dir01/ and /usr/local/dir02/. Names of dir01 and dir02 are different but everything downward is mirror picture.

Comment: @EEAA: None of my directories is mentioned in 'mount' output.

Comment: @bangal: Yes, as you can see in my reply to dr01 I'm talking about two directories on separate locations. 'incrontab -l' throws "no table for root".

Comment: @Reb, it means incron is installed in your system. Can you see if there is a file named: `/etc/incron.allow` and check it contents.

Answer (score 2):

`ls -s` shows the file sizes, not the symlinks.  Try the command `ls -lap` and most likely you'll see that your directories are symlinked.

`file mydir` will also tell you if the *mydir* directory is a symlink.

Comment: I tried ls -lap, but no symlinks were found. Looks like this was not my problem.  Thanks dr01.

Answer (score 1):

#### Symlink

You can check the type of a file with the `file` command (note: do not include trailing slash on a dir).

Example:

```
$ file /bin 
/bin: symbolic link to usr/bin
$ file /usr/bin
/usr/bin: directory
```

#### Bind Mount

Allows you to mount a portion of a filesystem in another location. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html for details.

You can see a list of bind mounts by running `findmnt | fgrep [`

Comment: It all ooks like this is my problem.
List of bind mounts is:
└─/dir01       /dev/mapper/centos-root[/usr/local/dir02] ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered
I should probably proceed with unmount /dir01?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that these two are directories synced automatically with **[incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en)**.

Here is a detailed link on  [how to trigger commands on File/Directory changes with Incron on Debian](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/trigger-commands-on-file-or-directory-changes-with-incron/)

> Incron is similar to cron, but instead of running commands based on
>   time, it can trigger commands when file or directory events occur
>   (e.g. a file modification, changes of permissions, etc.).

Since it seems, your computer have incron installed, you may look for possible configuration files (`/etc/incron.allow`, user's `incrontab`) and check how it is configured. While making some changes to the directory, logs should be seen also in syslog. See `man incrontab` for more info.

*Can not say it for sure, but it's possible.*